# Как правильно называется отличие между 0x000000 и #000000?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, color, веб-дизайн

Есть цвет, который обозначается `0x000000`, а есть `#000000`.

Как правильно называется различие между ними?

Вот первый вариант, если не ошибаюсь 16-ричный формат..

Comment: Не поверите, второй тоже 16'ричный формат :)

Comment: @Dmitry: не удивлён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, это просто разные символы для обозначения одного и того же шестнадцатиричного формата записи числа. В отличие от Вас интерпретатору точно надо знать, какую именно систему счисления Вы там используете и что бы отличать как-то основания, проставляются разные символы. В данном случае оба символа означают одно и то же 0x{hex} = #{hex} = hex.

Как правило об этом говорят просто "форма записи" числа.

Answer (score 1):

и второй тоже)) hex если по другому

Comment: Я не удивлен что он тоже 16ричный и что он тоже hex. Но ведь должно же быть у различий название..

Comment: @Shatal, ну назовите их для себя, например, *C-style Hex* и *Hash-Hex*.